# Mod shutdown command to sleep

Tags: windows-7

I want prevent me from shutdown windows.
So i would like to modify shutdown command in start menu to sleep my OS.

Is this possible via some register editing or so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

for windows 7 easy can do it with power option in control panel

see picture for edit power button to sleep

[image]

Comment: Unfortunatelly i have only Power Button action there, not Start menu power button, but thanks for your time Mohammad!